# Elegant way to avoid duplicate code for looping through different depths of a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, code-duplication

I have a nested dictionary `data` of depth 3. So `data[key1]` is a dictionary, `data[key1][key2]` is also a dictionary and `data[key1][key2][key3]` is numerical.

I need to loop through different depths and at the moment I do that with several functions that share a lot of code. I've marked the only 3 lines that differ in the example below. How can I avoid code duplicates?

```
def plot_measured_vs_fixed(data, noise, metric, aois, nfig):
    n_aois = len(aois)
    plt.figure(nfig, figsize=(FIGURE_SIZE*n_aois,FIGURE_SIZE)).clf()
    tilts = ["measured","fixed"]  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE!
    ymin, ymax = np.inf, -np.inf
    for i in range(n_aois):
        if i == 0:
            ax = ax0 = plt.subplot(1,n_aois,1)
        else:
            ax = plt.subplot(1,n_aois,i+1, sharey=ax0)
            plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
        aoi = aois[i]
        values = [data[tilt][aoi+metric][noise] for tilt in tilts] # <<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE!
        barplot(tilts, values, aoi) # <<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE!
        vmin, vmax = min(values), max(values)
        if ymin > vmin:
            ymin = vmin
        if ymax < vmax:
            ymax = vmax
    d = (ymax - ymin) / 4
    ymin, ymax = ymin - d, ymax + d
    plt.ylabel(metric+" (%)", size=20)
    plt.ylim(ymin,ymax)
    plt.title(metric)
    plt.tight_layout()

def plot_base_vs_worst(data, tilt, metric, aois, nfig):
    n_aois = len(aois)
    plt.figure(nfig, figsize=(FIGURE_SIZE*n_aois,FIGURE_SIZE)).clf()
    noises = ["base","worst"] # <<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE!
    ymin, ymax = np.inf, -np.inf
    for i in range(n_aois):
        if i == 0:
            ax = ax0 = plt.subplot(1,n_aois,1)
        else:
            ax = plt.subplot(1,n_aois,i+1, sharey=ax0)
            plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
        aoi = aois[i]
        values = [data[tilt][aoi+metric][noise] for noise in noises] # <<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE!
        barplot(noises, values, aoi) # <<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE!
        vmin, vmax = min(values), max(values)
        if ymin > vmin:
            ymin = vmin
        if ymax < vmax:
            ymax = vmax
    d = (ymax - ymin) / 4
    ymin, ymax = ymin - d, ymax + d
    plt.ylim(ymin,ymax)
    plt.ylabel(metric+" (%)", size=20)
    plt.title(metric)
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Inside the second function you are using a variable `noise` which isn't defined. Is this a mistake?

Comment: yes that was a typo just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is python. You can define the function such that both tilt and noise are specifyable. 
Depending on which is set, you use one parameter (and the other's list) or the other. Quick sketch on how that may look:

```
def plot_index_diff(data, metric, aois, nfig, noise="", tilt=""):
    ...
    noises = ["base","worst"]
    tilts = ["measured","fixed"]
    if tilt != "":
        values = [data[tilt][aoi+metric][name] for name in noises]
        barplot(noises, values, aoi)
    if noise != "":
        values = [data[name][aoi+metric][noise] for name in noises]
        barplot(tilts, values, aoi)
    ...
```

Chances are that if you redesign your interface a little, things get even easier.

Comment: Good idea. That works. However can you think of a better way to handle that if I had a nested dictionary of crazy depth? You wouldn't want to write many `if key_x != None:` blocks...

Comment: @JulienBernu If you want flexible depth, then you want key sets outside the function. With that, you get signature `data, metric, aois, nfig, aoipos, fixed_tuple, varpos, varvalue`. 
In this case, data has depth len(fixed_tuple)+2 (for aoi and varvalue). Insert each varvalue at position varpos into fixed_tuple.
A helper called ` dict_at(data, depth, tuple)` can then be used to retrieve the dictionary value (decrement depth on recursion call).